# How to store String output to an array in Java

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am getting a string output to this `c.getString(0)` method. I want to know how do I store this output into an array in Java? This `c.getString(0)` method is in a while loop. Each time the while loop runs, I want to store whatever the value I get with `c.getString(0)` method to store in an array. How can I do that?

```
private void showList() {

    DataBaseHelper db = new DataBaseHelper(this);
        db.open();
    c = db.retriveall();
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "_id: " + c.getString(0) + "\n",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }

}
```

For now I'm showing it an toast message. Instead of showing I want to store it to an array. please help me

Answer (score 2):

To store the data you can do several things:

- Use a String Array, if you know the number of items.
- Use a String ArrayList, if you dont know the number of items.

If you are using the array, the declare the String array,

```
String arr[]=new String[numberOfItems];
```

and then every time you are iterating the loop write:

```
arr[position++]=c.getString(position);
```

Now if you are using Array List then Declare the Array List:

```
ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
```

and then every time you iterate through the loop:

```
list.add(c.getString(position));
```

After this to get the elements you can write a foreach loop.

```
for(String ele: list){
   Toast.makeText(context,ele,Toast.LENGTH_SORT).show();
}
```

Comment: P.S. Producing toasts in a loop is a very bad idea. :P

Comment: Yes. I just gave an example! Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

Use `ArrayList`. They are dynamic i.e. needs no initial length. Use the `ArrayList.add()` method to add elements to the `ArrayList` and use `ArrayList.toArray()` to get an array if you need one. 
More information from the official docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Answer (score 0):

Create one global variable like,

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Inside your loop, you can add this code,

```
list.add(c.getString(0));
```

later you can convert it into array using `list.toArray()` method.

If you want to store the `String` value by character wise then use `toCharArray()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code:

```
List<String> globalList = new ArrayList<String>();
private void showList() {

DataBaseHelper db = new DataBaseHelper(this);
    db.open();
c = db.retriveall();
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                "_id: " + c.getString(0) + "\n",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        globalList.add(c.getString(0)) ;
    } while (c.moveToNext());
}

String [] a = globalList.toArray(new String[globalList.size()]);
```

}